# How do i use flask-admin column_sortable_list with a database relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm making a `flask` website that uses `flask-admin` for database management. I am trying to sort a column that contains a foreign key.

One of my flask-admin model views is for an intermediate table, i would like to sort the table on my view by a column that is a relationship to another table. for some reason `column_default_sort = 'pizza_id'` sorts the list but `column_sortable_list = ('pizza_id',)` does not work

here is how it looks currently
[image: table in view]
what i would like is for the `Pizza` table header to be blue like it is for `Id` meaning it can click it and it will sort by that column. an example is given below

[image: Imgur]

here are my sqlalchemy models

```py
class Topping(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'toppings'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Pizza(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pizza'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    extra_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    toppings = db.relationship('Topping', secondary='pizza_toppings')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


# my pizza intermediate table
class PizzaTopping(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pizza_toppings'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    pizza = db.relationship('Pizza', primaryjoin='PizzaTopping.pizza_id == Pizza.id', backref='pizza_toppings')
    topping = db.relationship('Topping', primaryjoin='PizzaTopping.topping_id == Topping.id', backref='pizza_toppings')

    pizza_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('pizza.id'), nullable=False)
    topping_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('toppings.id'), nullable=False)
```

here is my flask-admin model view

```py
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    can_set_page_size = True
    page_size = 15
    column_display_pk = True
    column_display_all_relations = True
    column_sortable_list = ('pizza_id',)
    column_default_sort = 'pizza_id'
    can_export = True

    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.has_roles(("owner", 'admin'))

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        return redirect('/')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dotted relationship attribute. e.g. to sort by pizza name or topping name:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):

    # ...
    column_sortable_list = ('pizza.name', 'topping.name', 'id')
    # ...
```

Comment: I used to check that I cand add "id" to `list_columns` and it will display, but didn't found how to add "id" field to the rest of the current fields. I'm really fuzzed that someone decided to remove ID from the result.

Comment: Found it, very sorry. The property is called `column_display_pk = True`

Answer (score 2):

the accepted answer didn't work for me. If it didn't work for someone else here's how I solved the issue:

1st way if you have declared the relationship in the model with the foreign key like the  example above your answer would look something like this:

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
    column_sortable_list = ('pizza', ('pizza_id', Pizza.name)) # or more generally: ('RelationshipName', ('Foreign Key you want to sort', ModelName.ColumnYouWantToSortBy))
```

2nd way if you were like me and you had your relationships defined in the model the Foreign key references. In this case:

```
class PizzaTopping(db.Model):
...
pizza_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('pizza.id'), nullable=False)
...

class Pizza(db.Model):
...
pizza = db.relationship('PizzaTopping', backref='pizza_toppings')
...
```

Now in model view all you have to change is instead of RelationshipName use the backref.

```
class MyModelView(ModelView):
     column_sortable_list = ('pizza_toppings', ('pizza_id', Pizza.name))
```